# Styling the Facebook login button next to other login links

Tags: html, css, layout, styling

I am trying to add the Facebook login button to my header, but for some reason it appears way left and to the bottom of other links :)

I am testing this out on this test page: http://www.comehike.com/test_fb_connect.php

I was trying to get the button to appear just left of the login link on top right of the page.  How can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you put it all in the same div?

```
<div class="site_login">
  <div class="facebook" >
   <fb:login-button show-faces="false" perms="user_about_me,email,user_location" autologoutlink="true" width="200" max-rows="1"> 
</fb:login-button> 
   </div>
   <div class="mylogin">
      <a class="login_link" id="login" href="/auth/log_in.php">Log in</a> |
      <a href="/auth/create_profile.php">Sign up</a> |
      <a href="/auth/forgot_password.php">Forgot Password</a> 
   </div>
</div>
```

now you can style using :

```
.facebook {
  ...
}

.mylogin {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Ok somehow managed it without wrapping it into a div.  Would still be nice to get styling for the div if that is considered better practice to place it inside div.

Comment: looks like you found a solution already. what you can do is give your site_login a width and height, and float:left both .facebook and .myloging, you can then play with the margin to align it correctly