# can I change the facebook login button size in my site?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I make Facebook log in in my site the login button code is

```
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>
```

can I change this button to the usually buttons or change its size

Comment: you could make custom button

Answer (score 1):

Add width attribute in login button:

```
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();" width="200px">
</fb:login-button>
```

Or else:

add your button with in div and apply css style to div.

```
<div class="site_login">
  <div class="facebook" >
   <fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();" width="200px">
</fb:login-button>
   </div>
```

Now you can apply style like this:

```
.facebook {
  width:300px;
  heigth:100px;
}
```

Ref: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948095/styling-the-facebook-login-button-next-to-other-login-links)

Answer (score 1):

```
<fb:login-button size="large"
                 scope="public_profile,email" 
                 onlogin="checkLoginState();">
```

or

```
size="xlarge"
```

like this You will use.